# Awk Printf result of a subtraction between column and fixed value

Tags: awk, printf

Let's say I have:

```
David    1500     2338    Baker
Danny    1290     1550    Bold
Domminic    25     28    Baker
```

So there are 4 tab-separated columns. size of all columns can vary a lot.
What I would like is a solution using awk printf to do : $2 - 1 for each line.
Here is the result I would like:

```
David    1499     2338    Baker
Danny    1289     1550    Bold
Domminic    24     28    Baker
```

And Finally here is what I have done so far:

```
awk '{if($0 ~/^D/) \
    {printf ("%s\t%d\t%d\t%s\n",$1,($2 - 1),$3,$4)}}'
```

Obviously if I am asking this question, it's because I do not get the expected result. This is what I obtain:

```
David    1500-1     2338    Baker
Danny    1290-1     1550    Bold
Domminic    25-1     28    Baker
```

I tried other stuff but it did not worked better...It is really important to me to get a solution in awk with printf.
"help me obi wan kenobi you're my only hope"!

Edit: I made a little mistake in the printf "format" part, the last \t should be a \n .
And then the problem is solved I don't understand why I get this error before. Big thank to Ed for the help (see comment). The awk command is now working.

Comment: you could try `awk  '{print $1, $2-1, $3, $4}' yourfile`

Comment: It is not possible to get the output you say you do from the command you say you ran. [edit] your question to show the command you REALLY ran to produce that output and to show the output you REALLY get from that command. Doing that latter will, I suspect, show you an answer to your question.

Comment: Hi Ed,
I have, indeed, made a little misstake : the end of printf format is not "\t" but "\n" . So I am going to edit it.
Maybe if you did not get the good result after this modification, it's because I only describe the awk part of my script, because the problem is coming from there. 
And you are right I don't understand, but my awk command is working now !
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make it *simpler* by setting input and output field separators to <kbd>Tab</kbd> and modify the `$2` value as

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{$2=$2-1}1' file
```

You don't need `printf` at all here. Once the field separators are set, the individual fields can be accessed as `$1`..`$NF`. Since the value we are concerned is in `$2`, just subtract one from it.

The default `print` action (implied by always-true pattern `1`) will rebuild the output line from the fields based on the output field separator (`OFS`) set.
 Since we are modifying only `$2` here, the other fields remain intact.

Comment: Nicely done, although it's worth noting that the (re)construction of the output line based on `OFS` happens at the time of _assigning_ to a field variable (`$2` in this case). `$2 -= 1` or `$2--` would work too.

Answer (score 2):

here is another `awk`

```
$ awk '/^D/{$2--}1' file | column -t

David     1499  2338  Baker
Danny     1289  1550  Bold
Domminic  24    28    Baker
```

or, add `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` for tabular in/out.